# How to keep python server running

Tags: python, django

I need a bit of help here. I am new to python and django. For my project i am developing an system which deals with api fetching and insertions. I need this system to be online 24 * 7. so i need to the server to be running all the time.
Using the traditional method of:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

runs perfectly.
I even tried :

```
nohup python manage.py &
```

but when i access my project with the url. Its showing that it project is not online. How do i fix this?

Comment: The solution is not to use the development server in production, but to use a real web server. Django's docs cover [deployment](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/) in great detail.

Comment: what is you server? are you accessing through apache and nginx or nginx and guinicorn

Comment: @Exprator 
I am using apache.

Comment: @DanielRoseman
Are you suggesting that i check the settings in my django configure the files in the server.?

Comment: I have no idea what that question means. I am suggesting that you deploy with a real server.

Comment: and i guess the server is ubuntu? so install a software called screen and in the screen run python manage.py runserver and it will run 24*7 untill you close the connection manually

Comment: No, no, no. You don't run a server in a screen session. Ever. This is wrong on so many levels it would deserve a full answer on all the ways it is wrong for. Instead, follow Django official documentation on [deployment](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/) that Daniel Roseman linked above.

Comment: If you're using Apache, the easiest solution is probably to use mod_wsgi as your WSGI server, see [How to use Django with Apache and mod_wsgi](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache then `mod_wsgi` should be used along with Django for deployment. This is covered [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) in great detail.

If you want step by step guide then you can have a look at [Digital Ocean's Guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Your Apache configuration will look like following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Alias /static /home/user/myproject/static
    <Directory /home/user/myproject/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/user/myproject/myproject>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-path=/home/user/myproject python-home=/home/user/myproject/myprojectenv
    WSGIProcessGroup myproject
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py

</VirtualHost>
```

You will need to create a `wsgi.py` file which looks like following(the default one):

````
"""
WSGI config for myproject project.
It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named        
```application```.
For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
````

Hope this helps.